# Angular using ngTemplateOutlet for a custom select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a custom select dropdown component that can be easily implemented by other devs in the following way:

```
<ui-select placeholder="select an option" label="Select">
  <ui-select-option *ngFor="let option of options" [id]="option">
    <!-- any custom content to display for the option -->
  </ui-select-option>
</ui-select>
```

I am using @ContentChildren along with ngTemplateOutlet to project each option into the options list (this allows me to wrap each option in a list item which can handle click events/selected css state etc.).

This is all working fine, however when I select an option, I want the template from the selected option to populate in the select input box. When I do this, the option magically disappears from the list.

I've created a minimal reproduction on stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ackvfp).

I've found a way that works with structural directives (https://stackblitz.com/edit/templateref-to-multiple-outlets), however I was hoping to avoid this, since to loop a bunch of options and render them would require an additional ng-container for the loop, since only one directive can exist on each component (would end up looking like the below):

```
<ui-select placeholder="select an option" label="Select">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of options">
    <ui-select-option *myValue="option">
      <!-- any custom content to display for the option -->
    </ui-select-option>
  </ng-container>
</ui-select>
```

(EDIT): I posed the same question direct to the angular team and they've done a good job of explaining the issue: [Using ngTemplateOutlet for a custom select dropdown](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46751)

Comment: I don't have an answer yet. But I upvoted because this is the finest example of how to correctly ask  a stackoverflow question that I've seen in a while. Kudos!

Comment: A really interesting problem. So far, I've isolated it to line 55 of select.component.ts. If you remove the ng-container tag and simply put in  ```{{i}}``` things work as expect as shown here. Now the question is why :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbtzmz

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! So I started by using ng-content, but quickly found that you can't use it to project the same thing into 2 places, and from there found ngTemplateOutlet which I believed was going to help me project things as and where I needed, but as you've seen, it doesn't seem to work still. the weirdest thing to me is that once you select an option, it disappears from the list forever, even if you select another option!

Comment: It actually doesn't disappear. The DOM element is still there if you inspect AND you can select it and see the expected value display. But, as you say, after selection content projection doesn't work. But WHHHHYYYY. QQing more